# Error while installing jenkins in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

While installing jenkins in ubuntu getting the following error:
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 6007 (unattended-upgr)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Comment: DO you install the package as root?

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests you have another apt process using resources. Maybe you started updating using software center.

Wait for the other process to complete or if doesn't restart, if that's not the option then you can try killing dpkg. But that has to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu performs automatic updates in the background, process and package are called "unattended-upgrades".

Meanwhile, the package manager is locked to prevent multiple changes to the system at the same time.

It usually doesn't take long, you usually only have to wait a few minutes.

Don't reboot or shoot down "unattended-upgrades"!